# How the number of byte required for string representation is calculated

Tags: c, macros, long-integer, sizeof, string-literals

I am not sure how LEN(LONG_MAX) prints 19, it should be 8 only.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define STRING(x) #x
#define LEN(x) ((int)sizeof(STRING(x)) - (int)1)

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",LEN(LONG_MAX));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please refer respective `limits.h` file usually `/usr/include/limits.h`

Comment: *should be 8 only* ... a 32-bit value in decimal can need 12 bytes including the terminator, for example `"-2147483647\0"`

Comment: Please note that expressions in these constant expressions are *implementation defined*, so you should not have any expectations about their length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in the used by you system `sizeof( long )` is equal to `8`.

In this case the value of `LONG_MAX` is `9223372036854775807`. That is the number contains `19` digits.

Due to this macro

```
#define STRING(x) #x
```

the value is converted to the string literal `"9223372036854775807"`.

String literals are stored as character arrays with trailing terminating zero character `'\0'`. So `sizeof( "9223372036854775807" )` is equal to `20` (`19` plus one for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal).

As a result the whole expression produced by this macro

```
#define LEN(x) ((int)sizeof(STRING(x)) - (int)1)
```

is equal to `19`.

Pay attention to that in general such an approach might not work because definitions of names like LONG_MAX or ULONG_MAX are implementation defined. For example an unsigned integer constant can have a suffix as for example ul.

A more reliable method is to use standard C function `snprintf` instead of the macros. For example

```
int n = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%llu", ULLONG_MAX );
printf( "n = %d\n", n );
```

Comment: For ULONG_MAX the max value is 18446744073709551615 thus the LEN() should return only 20 but returns 33.

Comment: @Weather Vane, could you add some pointers.

Comment: @PaulsonRajaL Actually the result is implementation defined depending on how ULONG_MAX is defined. For example an integer constant can have a suffix like ul or there can be other features. So in general such an approach will not work.